# Why there is no Queue or Stack API in jdk

Tags: java, collections, queue

I wanted to use Queues in java and I was searching it in the Collections.
Why it is not implemented in jdk.

Though its easy to implement and I did implement one to use it.

I just wanted to know if there is any design, implementation detail or any other reason for not implementing it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html unless you see anything missing in these.

Comment: Thanks Nambari. Can you post it as an answer. I can accept it.

Comment: @jdero. I made that comment before you made the edit :-)

Comment: I think it is better to accept one from existing, doesn't make sense to have so many duplicate answer.

Comment: Agreed. But have to wait for some more time to accept the answer :-)

Comment: This whole Question seems to be founded on the OPs inability to search / navigate / read the javadocs.  There *are* queue and stack classes in the Java SE library, and they are easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, didn't realize my queue was still an interface.

Use this [queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)...

```
public class ArrayDeque<E>
extends AbstractCollection<E>
implements Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

and... oh look. [a stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is, for instance, [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which implements `Deque`, which has methods to be used as either a Stack or Queue. There's even a Stack class, but it doesn't belong to the Collections Framework.

Comment: LinkedList??? I cant find it either. Can you give me the package structure or java doc location

Comment: @rozar - If you cannot find `LinkedList` in the javadocs (given the name) ... you don't know how to navigate the javadocs.  Look in the "all classes" list ...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the shortcoming in the stack, and have created a stack implementation myself. It can be fount at [Sourceforge](http://www.sourceforge.com/p/jrestack). You may want to use it.